# Find the most frequent seen column_name using max

Tags: sql, postgresql, count, max, having

I have a table named `food`:

```
CREATE TABLE food
(
    name varchar(30) primary key,
    type varchar(30)
);
```

I want to find the `type` that appears the most time in this table.

I can find this using

```
SELECT type
FROM food
GROUP BY type
ORDER BY count(type) DESC
LIMIT 1
```

But `limit 1` is not in included in the standards. How can I find the same result using `MAX`? For example I want something like

```
SELECT type
FROM food
GROUP BY type
HAVING count(type) = MAX(count(type));
```

`HAVING count(type) = MAX(count(type));` isn't allowed.

Comment: The ANSI SQL alternative to `LIMIT 1` is `FETCH FIRST 1 ROW`. Add `WITH TIES` and you'll get both rows if two types have the same maximum number of rows. (Unfortunately not supported by so many dbms products yet.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

May not be efficient

```
SELECT type
FROM food
GROUP BY type
HAVING COUNT(type) =
(
    SELECT MAX(counting) FROM
    (
        SELECT COUNT(type) AS counting
        FROM food
        GROUP BY type
    ) t
)
```

Answer (score 1):

Use a cte (common table expression) where you do the `GROUP BY` with `COUNT`:

```
with cte as
(
    SELECT type, count(*) as cnt
    FROM food
    GROUP BY type
)
select type from cte
where cnt = (select max(cnt) from cte)
```

Will return both rows if there's a tie.

(I don't know if this will have same or better performance compared to Madhivanan's answer. Less typing anyway.)